# Cakephp memory limit error after migration, troubleshooting Controller

Tags: php, memory, cakephp, centos7

I'm copying/migrating a production server Cakephp 2.3.8 project into a development one but I get the famous error:

> Blockquote
> Fatal Error
> Error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 200648563 bytes)
> File: /var/www/html/lib/Cake/Utility/String.php
> Line: 243

> Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/View/Errors/fatal_error.ctp

I have already mirror the same specs that the production server:

- Tried to increase the default memory limit on apache > php.ini file from 128M to 1024
- Also 1024 to 2048, but no luck
- Restarted the server and apache service
- Limit the data set on my database (currently have 6, but the production server has about 40K rows on the table that I'm querying)
- Tested a function inside the controller to just display a single line of text (successfully displays it, but the Fatal error message keeps showing up).

This mostly happens when I visit certain controllers because I'm able to load some pages correctly (apparently).

I'm currently debugging the behavior of the app on the log files:

- /ppp/tmp/logs/error.log
- Xdebug

But none of them shows more details that the Fatal error limit, I was told that it might be a memory leak, buy how come if both servers are limited the same way ? (ulimit for servers below).

I would like to know what the problem is, I'm I missing a setting? How could I adjust a Controller in a way to run without errors?

**Dev server specs**

- Centos 7
- PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Apr  1 2020 04:07:17) 
  Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
  Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
  with Xdebug v2.2.7, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
- VPS on Linode: 2 cores 4 GB of RAM
- Ulimit:
  core file size          (blocks, -c) 0 
  data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited 
  scheduling priority             (-e) 0 
  file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited 
  pending signals                 (-i) 15076 
  max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64 
  max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited 
  open files                      (-n) 1024 
  pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8 
  POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200 
  real-time priority              (-r) 0 
  stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192 
  cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited 
  max user processes              (-u) 15076 
  virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited 
  file locks                      (-x) unlimited

**Production server**

- Centos 7
- PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Apr  1 2020 04:07:17) 
  Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
  Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
- Dedicated server: 16 cores (32 threads), 128Gb of RAM
- Ulimit:
  core file size          (blocks, -c) 0 
  data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited 
  scheduling priority             (-e) 0 
  file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited 
  pending signals                 (-i) 514324 
  max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64 
  max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited 
  open files                      (-n) 8192 
  pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8 
  POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200 
  real-time priority              (-r) 0
  stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
  cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
  max user processes              (-u) 8192
  virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
  file locks                      (-x) unlimited

Thanks in advance


**UPDATE 1**
This is what it shows up after copying lib/Cake/View/Errors/fatal_error.ctp to app/View/Errors/fatal_error.ctp and adding

```
<pre><?php echo h($error->getTraceAsString()); ?></pre>
```

> Fatal Error
> Error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 126212148 bytes)
> File: /var/www/html/lib/Cake/Utility/String.php
> Line: 243
>
> Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/View/Errors/fatal_error.ctp
>
> July 9th '20 Update
>
> #0 /var/www/html/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php(184): ErrorHandler::handleFatalError(1, 'Allowed memory ...', '/var/www/html/l...', 243)
>
> #1 [internal function]: ErrorHandler::handleError(1, 'Allowed memory ...', '/var/www/html/l...', 243, Array)
>
> #2 /var/www/html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php(931): call_user_func('ErrorHandler::h...', 1, 'Allowed memory ...', '/var/www/html/l...', 243, Array)
>
> #3 /var/www/html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php(904): App::_checkFatalError()
>
> #4 [internal function]: App::shutdown()
>
> #5 {main}

Before that I was taking out some Components and helpers:

```
var $helpers=array("Js","Html","Form","Paginator","Fck","Cache","Pagination");
var $components=array("Customcomponent","Paginator","RequestHandler","Cookie","Pagination","Email");
```

But no luck (got same error message), my other Controller that works doesn't use helpers, only the following components:

```
var $components=array("Customcomponent","RequestHandler","Cookie","Email","Pagination","Paginator");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what called `String.php Line: 243`, full callstack might help

Copy `lib/Cake/View/Errors/fatal_error.ctp` to `app/View/Errors/fatal_error.ctp` and add

```
<pre><?php echo h($error->getTraceAsString()); ?></pre>
```

Comment: Post updated, is the message useful? Sound something related to Cakephp library?

Comment: Unfortunately error is during shutdown and doesn't give more useful information.

 I suspect that it happens during rendering original error, but error output is too large.

Try use same production settings (debug off, error logging on), maybe it will work.

Comment: Wow it worked! Something shows up, why so? I changed the value 2 --> 0 on  Configure::write('debug',0);

Comment: I suspect that CakePHP tried to render another error, but it contained variables with big tree, maybe recursive variables.
Check error log, it might contain original error just before memory limit error.

Comment: No, messages on error/debug.log, I guess I have to keep testing it.

Comment: Try to add `if (strlen($str) > 10000000) { exit($str); }` in `lib/Cake/Utility/String.php Line: 243`. Sometimes only such hackish methods helps...

Comment: `foreach ($dataReplacements as $tmpHash => $tmpValue) {
   $tmpValue = (is_array($tmpValue)) ? '' : $tmpValue;
   if (strlen($str) > 10000000) { exit($str); }
   $str = str_replace($tmpHash, $tmpValue, $str);
  }`

Comment: I have put your suggestion to line 242 and changed debug 0 to 2. But nothing seems like the view couldn't be drawn, got a couple of warnings and notice: `Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/lib/Cake/Utility/Debugger.php:806) [APP/Controller/CompaniesController.php, line 3662]`.No logs/debug files generated.

Comment: There was some output before `APP/Controller/CompaniesController.php, line 3662`. If you use `xdebug`, add breakpoint at `lib/Cake/Utility/Debugger.php:806`. It is hard to say anything why normal error reporting/logging doesn't work.